# Can't convert OcTree to Fcl

Tags: ros, octomap, ros-kinetic, fcl, octree

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm trying to create a code for 2D collision checking using fcl and octomap.

Here i'm trying to convert the octomap::octree to fcl::octree so that i can use the function: "generateBoxesFromOctomap".

I am following this program as a guide: [link](https://github.com/erwincoumans/fcl/blob/master/test/test_fcl_octomap.cpp)

I'm using ROS kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04, fcl is version 0.6.

This is my code:

```
   OcTree* octTree = new OcTree(0.1);
   Pointcloud octPointCloud;
   
   for (int x=-20; x<20; x++) {
   for (int y=-20; y<20; y++) {
   point3d endpoint ((float) x*0.05f, (float) y*0.05f, (float) 0.0);
   if (endpoint.x() < 0.7 && endpoint.x() > 0.3 && endpoint.y()< 0.6 && endpoint.y() > 0.8)          //size of the obstacle
   octPointCloud.push_back(endpoint); 
      } 
    }
  point3d origin(0.0,0.0,0.0);
  octTree->insertPointCloud(octPointCloud,origin);
  octTree->updateInnerOccupancy();     
  
  //convert the octomap 
  fcl::OcTree<double>* tree2 = new fcl::OcTree(boost::shared_ptr<const octomap::OcTree>(octTree));
  std::vector<fcl::CollisionObject<double>*> boxes;
  generateBoxesFromOctomap(boxes, *tree2);
```

but i get this error:

```
error: expected type-specifier
  fcl::OcTree<double>* tree2 = new fcl::OcTree(boost::shared_ptr<const octomap::OcTree>(octTree))
```

What can i do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321069/can%27t-convert-octree-to-fcl/) by [Costuz](https://answers.ros.org/users/40872/costuz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-04-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2019-04-14**:
In a similar working example I have, I am using : `fcl::OcTree* tree2`, try without using the  maybe

**Comment by [Costuz](https://answers.ros.org/users/40872/costuz/) on 2019-04-14**:
Now it gives me two more error:

```
 error: missing template arguments before ‘*’ token
        fcl::OcTree* tree2 = new fcl::OcTree(boost::shared_ptr<const octomap::OcTree
                   ^
    error: ‘tree2’ was not declared in this scope
        fcl::OcTree* tree2 = new fcl::OcTree(boost::shared_ptr<const octomap::OcTree
                     ^
    error: expected type-specifier
       fcl::OcTree* tree2 = new fcl::OcTree(boost::shared_ptr<const octomap::OcTree
                                ^
```

don't know what to do

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2019-04-14**:
My fault, my previous comment is for `CollisionGeometry` type and not `ColiisionObject`. But, according to this [test file](https://github.com/flexible-collision-library/fcl/blob/master/test/test_fcl_octomap_collision.cpp#L181), you should have `fcl::OcTree<double>* tree2 = new fcl::OcTree<double>(std::shared_ptr<const octomap::OcTree>(octTree));`

**Comment by [Costuz](https://answers.ros.org/users/40872/costuz/) on 2019-04-14**:
Yes, now it works
Thanks for your help!

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2019-04-14**:
Added the answer below, you may mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to this [test file](https://github.com/flexible-collision-library/fcl/blob/master/test/test_fcl_octomap_collision.cpp#L181), you should have `fcl::OcTree<double>* tree2 = new fcl::OcTree<double>(std::shared_ptr<const octomap::OcTree>(octTree));`
instead of   `fcl::OcTree<double>* tree2 = new fcl::OcTree(boost::shared_ptr<const octomap::OcTree>(octTree));`

---

Originally posted by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) with karma: 210 on 2019-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0